# scikits-learn pca dimension reduction issue

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I have a problem with reduction dimension using scikit-learn and PCA.

I have two numpy matrices, one has size (1050,4096) and another has size (50,4096). I tried to reduce the dimensions of both to yield (1050, 399) and (50,399) but, after doing the pca I got (1050,399) and (50,50) matrices. One matrix is for knn training and another for knn test. What's wrong with my code below?

```
pca = decomposition.PCA()
pca.fit(train)
pca.n_components = 399
train_reduced = pca.fit_transform(train)
pca.n_components = 399
pca.fit(test)
test_reduced = pca.fit_transform(test)
```

Answer (score 15):

Call `fit_transform()` on train, `transform()` on test:

```
from sklearn import decomposition

train = np.random.rand(1050, 4096)
test = np.random.rand(50, 4096)

pca = decomposition.PCA()
pca.n_components = 399
train_reduced = pca.fit_transform(train)
test_reduced = pca.transform(test)
```

Comment: Thanks HYRY, it works! But, if I have a third matrix to reduce dimension (forget about training and testing), which should I use? transform() or fit_transform()?

Comment: You should use `fit_transform()` for independent data. In case of (train, test) set, they are the same dataset, so you fit on the train data, and transform both the train and test data.

Comment: Instead of saying thanks twice @mad, accept the answer! You made a good question, I upvoted, you got a good answer, you accept it! Simple as that.